# "de grandes dores" é termo acessório na frase "pequenas faltas são causas de grandes dores"?

Tags: untagged

A frase "*pequenas faltas são causas de grandes dores*" não me parece ter sentido completo sem a parte "*de grandes dores*". "*Pequenas faltas são causas*", causas do quê? Alguém pode confirmar se "*de grandes dores*" é adjunto adnominal de causas, portanto, um termo acessório apenas.

Comment: Causas é um substantivo abstrato. "de grandes dores" é o complemento nominal de "causas".